# How do I read the entire body of a Tokio-based Hyper request?

Tags: rust, hyper, rust-tokio

I want to write a server using the current master branch of Hyper that saves a message that is delivered by a POST request and sends this message to every incoming GET request.

I have this, mostly copied from the Hyper examples directory:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate pretty_env_logger;

use futures::future::FutureResult;

use hyper::{Get, Post, StatusCode};
use hyper::header::{ContentLength};
use hyper::server::{Http, Service, Request, Response};
use futures::Stream;

struct Echo {
    data: Vec<u8>,
}

impl Echo {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Echo {
            data: "text".into(),
        }
    }
}

impl Service for Echo {
    type Request = Request;
    type Response = Response;
    type Error = hyper::Error;
    type Future = FutureResult<Response, hyper::Error>;

    fn call(&self, req: Self::Request) -> Self::Future {
        let resp = match (req.method(), req.path()) {
            (&Get, "/") | (&Get, "/echo") => {
                Response::new()
                    .with_header(ContentLength(self.data.len() as u64))
                    .with_body(self.data.clone())
            },
            (&Post, "/") => {
                //self.data.clear(); // argh. &self is not mutable :(
                // even if it was mutable... how to put the entire body into it?
                //req.body().fold(...) ?
                let mut res = Response::new();
                if let Some(len) = req.headers().get::<ContentLength>() {
                    res.headers_mut().set(ContentLength(0));
                }
                res.with_body(req.body())
            },
            _ => {
                Response::new()
                    .with_status(StatusCode::NotFound)
            }
        };
        futures::future::ok(resp)
    }

}


fn main() {
    pretty_env_logger::init().unwrap();
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:12346".parse().unwrap();

    let server = Http::new().bind(&addr, || Ok(Echo::new())).unwrap();
    println!("Listening on http://{} with 1 thread.", server.local_addr().unwrap());
    server.run().unwrap();
}
```

How do I turn the `req.body()` (which seems to be a `Stream` of `Chunks`) into a `Vec<u8>`? I assume I must somehow return a `Future` that consumes the `Stream` and turns it into a single `Vec<u8>`, maybe with `fold()`. But I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: [How to share mutable state for a Hyper handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35678267/155423) answers half of your question, so I've reworded your question to focus on the unique aspect and help avoid downvotes.

Comment: Thank you for your first edit @Shepmaster. After that it looked really polished. However, I don't like your second edit. I don't see how the linked question answers my question. They don't even implement the trait Service.

Comment: You are always able to roll back any edit you disagree with from the [revision list](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43419974/revisions) or perform further edits.

Comment: However, the answer is the same, you will need thread-safe interior mutability such as a `Mutex`, `Atomic*`, or `RwLock`.

Comment: Please be aware that you are expected to [have one question per question, as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).

Comment: Ok, then I will just open a new question for the first one. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds good. In that case, I'd also advise you to create a [MCVE] and use a released version of Hyper. Linking to the question I suggested above and showing why it is not valid for your case will go a long way as well!

Comment: @Shepmaster seems like the Tokio developers want to [modify](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio-service/issues/9) or maybe even [delete](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio-service/issues/8) the `Service` trait. So maybe my other question will resolve itself, once tokio-service-0.2 is out.

Comment: Good to know, but `tokio::Service` is presumably different from `hyper::Service`, right? Even if Tokio removes it, would Hyper keep it?

Comment: @Shepmaster I assume Hyper just copied the trait, when they started to migrate to Tokio. But yeah, maybe they will keep it, even if Tokio does not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm going to simplify the problem to just return the total number of bytes, instead of echoing the entire stream.

## Futures 0.3

### Hyper 0.13 + `TryStreamExt::try_fold`

See [euclio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59428403/155423) about [`hyper::body::to_bytes`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.13.9/hyper/body/fn.to_bytes.html) if you just want all the data as one giant blob.

Accessing the stream allows for more fine-grained control:

```
use futures::TryStreamExt; // 0.3.7
use hyper::{server::Server, service, Body, Method, Request, Response}; // 0.13.9
use std::convert::Infallible;
use tokio; // 0.2.22

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:12346".parse().expect("Unable to parse address");

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(service::make_service_fn(|_conn| async {
        Ok::<_, Infallible>(service::service_fn(echo))
    }));

    println!("Listening on http://{}.", server.local_addr());

    if let Err(e) = server.await {
        eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
    }
}

async fn echo(req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, hyper::Error> {
    let (parts, body) = req.into_parts();
    match (parts.method, parts.uri.path()) {
        (Method::POST, "/") => {
            let entire_body = body
                .try_fold(Vec::new(), |mut data, chunk| async move {
                    data.extend_from_slice(&chunk);
                    Ok(data)
                })
                .await;

            entire_body.map(|body| {
                let body = Body::from(format!("Read {} bytes", body.len()));
                Response::new(body)
            })
        }
        _ => {
            let body = Body::from("Can only POST to /");
            Ok(Response::new(body))
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the current implementation of `Bytes` is no longer compatible with [`TryStreamExt::try_concat`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html#method.try_concat), so we have to switch back to a fold.

## Futures 0.1

### hyper 0.12 + `Stream::concat2`

Since futures 0.1.14, you can use [`Stream::concat2`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.concat2) to stick together all the data into one:

```
fn concat2(self) -> Concat2<Self>
where
    Self: Sized,
    Self::Item: Extend<<Self::Item as IntoIterator>::Item> + IntoIterator + Default,
```

```
use futures::{
    future::{self, Either},
    Future, Stream,
}; // 0.1.25

use hyper::{server::Server, service, Body, Method, Request, Response}; // 0.12.20

use tokio; // 0.1.14

fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:12346".parse().expect("Unable to parse address");

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(|| service::service_fn(echo));

    println!("Listening on http://{}.", server.local_addr());

    let server = server.map_err(|e| eprintln!("Error: {}", e));
    tokio::run(server);
}

fn echo(req: Request<Body>) -> impl Future<Item = Response<Body>, Error = hyper::Error> {
    let (parts, body) = req.into_parts();

    match (parts.method, parts.uri.path()) {
        (Method::POST, "/") => {
            let entire_body = body.concat2();
            let resp = entire_body.map(|body| {
                let body = Body::from(format!("Read {} bytes", body.len()));
                Response::new(body)
            });
            Either::A(resp)
        }
        _ => {
            let body = Body::from("Can only POST to /");
            let resp = future::ok(Response::new(body));
            Either::B(resp)
        }
    }
}
```

You could also convert the `Bytes` into a `Vec<u8>` via `entire_body.to_vec()` and then convert that to a `String`.

See also:

- [How do I convert a Vector of bytes (u8) to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19076719/155423)

### hyper 0.11 + `Stream::fold`

Similar to `Iterator::fold`, [`Stream::fold`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.fold) takes an *accumulator* (called `init`) and a function that operates on the accumulator and an item from the stream. The result of the function must be another future with the same error type as the original. The total result is itself a future.

```
fn fold<F, T, Fut>(self, init: T, f: F) -> Fold<Self, F, Fut, T>
where
    F: FnMut(T, Self::Item) -> Fut,
    Fut: IntoFuture<Item = T>,
    Self::Error: From<Fut::Error>,
    Self: Sized,
```

We can use a `Vec` as the accumulator. `Body`'s `Stream` implementation returns a `Chunk`. This implements `Deref<[u8]>`, so we can use that to append each chunk's data to the `Vec`.

```
extern crate futures; // 0.1.23
extern crate hyper;   // 0.11.27

use futures::{Future, Stream};
use hyper::{
    server::{Http, Request, Response, Service}, Post,
};

fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:12346".parse().unwrap();

    let server = Http::new().bind(&addr, || Ok(Echo)).unwrap();
    println!(
        "Listening on http://{} with 1 thread.",
        server.local_addr().unwrap()
    );
    server.run().unwrap();
}

struct Echo;

impl Service for Echo {
    type Request = Request;
    type Response = Response;
    type Error = hyper::Error;
    type Future = Box<futures::Future<Item = Response, Error = Self::Error>>;

    fn call(&self, req: Self::Request) -> Self::Future {
        match (req.method(), req.path()) {
            (&Post, "/") => {
                let f = req.body()
                    .fold(Vec::new(), |mut acc, chunk| {
                        acc.extend_from_slice(&*chunk);
                        futures::future::ok::<_, Self::Error>(acc)
                    })
                    .map(|body| Response::new().with_body(format!("Read {} bytes", body.len())));

                Box::new(f)
            }
            _ => panic!("Nope"),
        }
    }
}
```

You could also convert the `Vec<u8>` `body` to a `String`.

See also:

- [How do I convert a Vector of bytes (u8) to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19076719/155423)

## Output

When called from the command line, we can see the result:

```
$ curl -X POST --data hello http://127.0.0.1:12346/
Read 5 bytes
```

## Warning

All of these solutions allow a malicious end user to POST an infinitely sized file, which would cause the machine to run out of memory. Depending on the intended use, you may wish to establish some kind of cap on the number of bytes read, potentially writing to the filesystem at some breakpoint.

See also:

- [How do I apply a limit to the number of bytes read by futures::Stream::concat2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53142508/155423)

Comment: Could you also explain why you have `futures::future:ok()` in the fold method, although you deleted `FutureResult` from `type Future = ...`?

Comment: @JayStrictor because the closure given to `fold` needs to return a future itself: `F: FnMut(T, Self::Item) -> Fut`. This allows for the operation to itself take time. Since `extend_from_slice` is synchronous, we "lift" up the result using `future::ok`. This is pretty separate from the `type Future = FutureResult`, which is used as the return value of the handler (which I boxed out of laziness).

Comment: The `Stream::fold(...)` can be replaced with `Stream::concat2()` that does the same thing. `Chunk` is itself `Extend` so the result of `concat2` will be a single `Chunk` that contains the whole body.

Comment: @Arnavion thanks! When I wrote this answer originally, `concat2` didn't even exist!

Comment: What would be a technique to (for example) stop after 1MiB of input,  using concat2 ?

Comment: @proc [How do I apply a limit to the number of bytes read by futures::Stream::concat2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53142508/155423)

Comment: If you write data to the filesystem to avoid running out of memory, then you just allow an attacker to fill up your server's filesystems.  Don't do that.

Comment: @M.Leonhard ***you may wish to establish some kind of cap on the number of bytes read**, potentially writing to the filesystem at some breakpoint.* — my suggestion is not to write to the filesystem instead of just using memory, but in addition to an existing cap.

Answer (score 38):

Hyper 0.13 provides a [`body::to_bytes` function](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.13.2/hyper/body/fn.to_bytes.html) for this purpose.

```rust
use hyper::body;
use hyper::{Body, Response};

pub async fn read_response_body(res: Response<Body>) -> Result<String, hyper::Error> {
    let bytes = body::to_bytes(res.into_body()).await?;
    Ok(String::from_utf8(bytes.to_vec()).expect("response was not valid utf-8"))
}
```

Comment: Response [implements `HttpBody`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.13.1/hyper/body/trait.HttpBody.html#impl-Body-2) required by `to_bytes`, so no need to call `into_body()` explicitly. And `Bytes` implements `AsRef<[u8]>`, so you can avoid `Vec` allocation.

Answer (score 1):

For hyper 1.1.0, using `collect()` provided by `http-body-util` worked for me:

```
use anyhow::Result;
use http_body_util::BodyExt;
use hyper::body::Incoming;

async fn request_to_string(req: Request<Incoming>) -> Result<String> {
    String::from_utf8(req.into_body().collect().await?.to_bytes().into())?
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Most of the answers on this topic are outdated or overly complicated. The solution is pretty simple:

```rust
/*
    WARNING for beginners!!! This use statement
    is important so we can later use .data() method!!!
*/
use hyper::body::HttpBody;

let my_vector: Vec<u8> = request.into_body().data().await.unwrap().unwrap().to_vec();
let my_string = String::from_utf8(my_vector).unwrap();
```

You can also use `body::to_bytes` [as @euclio answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59428403/155423). Both approaches are straight-forward! Don't forget to handle `unwrap` properly.

Comment: [`data`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.13.9/hyper/body/trait.HttpBody.html#method.data) is documented as "Returns future that resolves to next data chunk, if any.", so I'm pretty sure that this answer is incorrect / incomplete.