# What is the proper way to extract the body of an actix_web Response into a string?

Tags: rust, actor, rust-actix

I am attempting to use [actix_web](https://crates.io/crates/actix-web) to fetch and display the contents of a web page.  The HTTP request completes successfully and I can view the webpage, but I want to read the body into a `String` for printing.

I tried `let my_ip: String = response.body().into();` but I get an error that says

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::string::String: std::convert::From<actix_web::httpmessage::MessageBody<actix_web::client::response::ClientResponse>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:16:53
   |
16 |                 let my_ip: String = response.body().into();
   |                                                     ^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<actix_web::httpmessage::MessageBody<actix_web::client::response::ClientResponse>>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <std::string::String as std::convert::From<&'a str>>
             <std::string::String as std::convert::From<std::borrow::Cow<'a, str>>>
             <std::string::String as std::convert::From<std::boxed::Box<str>>>
             <std::string::String as std::convert::From<trust_dns_proto::error::ProtoError>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<std::string::String>` for `actix_web::httpmessage::MessageBody<actix_web::client::response::ClientResponse>`
```

This is what I have so far:

```
use actix;
use actix_web::{client, HttpMessage};
use futures::future::Future;

fn main() {
    actix::run(|| {
        client::get("http://ipv4.canhasip.com/")
            .header("User-Agent", "Actix-web")
            .finish()
            .unwrap()
            .send()
            .map_err(|_| ())
            .and_then(|response| {
                println!("Response: {:?}", response);
                // error occurs here
                let my_ip: String = response.body().into();
                Ok(())
            })
    });
}
```

Relevant dependency versions:

```
[dependencies]
actix-web = "0.7"
actix = "0.7"
futures = "0.1"
```

Comment: @Shepmaster You're right, I've been on SO long enough to understand that my question left a lot to be desired.  I went through and clarified things and made sure that the error message exactly matched the example.

Comment: No worries; it's super easy to get caught up in a problem that we've been working on for a while and lose sight of the bigger picture!

Answer (score 6):

In order to keep the `response` object you have while also extracting the body, we're going to take advantage of the fact that, unlike a few other frameworks, you can extract the body without destructuring the entire object. Code is below:

```
actix::run(|| {

    client::get("http://localhost/")
        .header("User-Agent", "Actix-web")
        .finish()
        .unwrap()
        .send()
        .map_err(|e| {
          Error::new(ErrorKind::AddrInUse, "Request error", e)
        })
        .and_then(|response| {
          println!("Got response");
          response.body().map(move |body_out| {
            (response, body_out)
          }).map_err(|e| Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidData, "Payload error", e))
        }).and_then(|(response, body)| {
          println!("Response: {:?}, Body: {:?}", response, body);
          Ok(())
      }).map_err(|_| ())
});
```

In order:

- everything in there now uses `std::io::Error` for ease of use. Since all `actix` error types implement `Error`, it is also possible to preserve the original types
- `and_then()` allows me to extract the body. When this is resolved, a `map` (with `move` making sure we're taking `response` with us) then returns a tuple of `(response, body)`
- From there, you can freely use either the response or the body as you see fit

Do note that I replaced your hostname with `localhost` for testing purposes as `ipv4.canhasip.com` does not currently resolve to anything on the outside.

---

Initial answer:

You really should've provided more context on this one. `actix` has more than one request type.

Your initial object (`response`) is a [`ClientResponse`](https://actix.rs/api/actix-web/stable/actix_web/client/struct.ClientResponse.html). calling `body()` on it returns a `MessageBody` struct, which is the start of the rabbit hole you fell into. This is **NOT** the actual body, merely an object implementing the `Future` trait and which will, once it has run its course, yield what you are after.

You'll need to do this in a less hacky way, but for now and to convince yourself that this is the source of the issue, instead of your line of code, try this:

```
println!("{:?}", response.body().wait())
```

Calling `wait()` on a future blocks the current thread, which is why I am saying it is a temporary, hacky way to show you where the issue is. Depending on what you have at your disposal (if you have an executor-like object somewhere, or are able to return a future for execution), your actual solution will differ.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail.  I didn't realize there were multiple request types.  I've edited the question with an example.  See if that helps.

Comment: @BonsaiOak reply is delayed, work is being...unusually *interesting*. Editing the answer to provide a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing Sébastien's answer, you can also resolve the `MessageBody` future:

```
.and_then(|response| {
    response.body().map_err(|_| ()).and_then(|bytes| {
        println!("{:?}", bytes);
        Ok(())
    })
})
```

Comment: I didn't want to go that far as, due to the brevity of the OP's example, it isn't guaranteed that he isn't *already* returning something implementing `IntoFuture` from where he got that object, hence the caveat :-)

Comment: I've edited my question with an example.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
actix::run(|| {
    client::get("http://ipv4.canhasip.com/")
        .header("User-Agent", "Actix-web")
        .finish()
        .unwrap()
        .send()
        .map_err(drop)
        .and_then(|response| response.body().map_err(drop))
        .map(|body| body.to_vec())
        .map(|body| String::from_utf8(body).unwrap())
        .map(drop) // Do *something* with the string, presumably
});
```

The result of `send` is a [`SendRequest`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/0.7.17/actix_web/client/struct.SendRequest.html). This is a future that resolves into a [`ClientResponse`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/0.7.17/actix_web/client/struct.ClientResponse.html). `ClientResponse` implements `HttpMessage`, which has the method
[`HttpMessage::body`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/0.7.17/actix_web/trait.HttpMessage.html#method.body). This returns a future that resolves into a [`Bytes`](https://docs.rs/bytes/0.4.11/bytes/struct.Bytes.html). This can be converted into a `String` through the usual Rust methods.

See also:

- [How do I read the entire body of a Tokio-based Hyper request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43419974/155423)
- [How do I convert a Vector of bytes (u8) to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076719/how-do-i-convert-a-vector-of-bytes-u8-to-a-string)

Comment: What is the meaning of `drop` in `map_err`?

Comment: Looks like `drop` is a prelude function passed into `map_err` that throws away the error.
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/