# How can I mutate the HTML inside a hyper::Response?

Tags: http, rust, async-await, future, hyper

I am trying to parse and modify the HTML data contained within a `hyper::Response` from the [hyper](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.13.7/hyper/) HTTP crate:

```
async fn modify_response(response: ResponseFuture)
    -> Result<Response<hyper::Body>, hyper::Error> {
    let response = response.await;
    // extract HTML from Response
    // parse and modify HTML as a String
    // write the HTML into a new Response
}
```

Failed attempts:

- [This method](https://mmstick.gitbooks.io/rust-programming-phoronix-reader-how-to/content/chapter07.html) is outdated, back when `Response` implemented `Read`.
- `response.body()` returns `Body(Streaming)` rather than the response's HTML.

I know obtaining the HTML [is possible](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/blob/master/examples/simple.rs) because the `reqwest` crate (built on `hyper`) can extract it with `.text()`; however, my investigation of that source code has not revealed anything yet. Besides, I *also* want to insert the modified HTML *back into* a `Response`.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I read the entire body of a Tokio-based Hyper request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43419974/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you!