# How do I terminate a hyper server after fulfilling one request?

Tags: rust, hyper

I need a simple hyper server that serves a single request and then exits. This is my code so far, I believe that all I need is a way to get `tx` into `hello`, so I can use `tx.send(())` and it should work the way I want it. However, I can't quite work out a way to do that without having the compiler yell at me.

```
use std::convert::Infallible;

use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};
use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server};

async fn hello(_: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, Infallible> {
    Ok(Response::new(Body::from("Hello World!")))
}

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {

    let (tx, rx) = tokio::sync::oneshot::channel::<()>();

    let make_svc = make_service_fn(|_conn| {
        async { Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(hello)) }
    });

    let addr = ([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000).into();

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_svc);

    println!("Listening on http://{}", addr);

    let graceful = server.with_graceful_shutdown(async {
        rx.await.ok();
    });

    graceful.await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=598387e02d69abaa033bbc283a825408)

Relevant crates:

```
tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["full"] }
hyper = "0.13.7"
```

Since [How to share mutable state for a Hyper handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35678267/155423) and [How to share mutable state for a Hyper handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35678267/155423), the hyper API has changed and I am [unable to compile the code when edited to work with the current version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=454cc4133cd81b8f687ca01de1c2cc7a).

Comment: And how can **we** guess what the compiler yells?

Comment: Also it works just fine in a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e731afb3918589182bee624cd87d0739)

Comment: @AlexLarionov @Shepmaster There is no error with the current code. I am asking how to accomplish something, i.e how to use tx.send() from within the hello method. There is no way for me to post a full error message, there is no error message. My code is also present in fulI, there are no other types, traits or fields that I have not mentioned, all `use`'s are present, and all crates are the latest version. I have edited the post with the other details that you have asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A straightforward solution would be to use global state for this, made possible by tokio's `Mutex` type, like so:

```
use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};
use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server};
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::convert::Infallible;
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::oneshot::Sender;
use tokio::sync::Mutex;

lazy_static! {
    /// Channel used to send shutdown signal - wrapped in an Option to allow
    /// it to be taken by value (since oneshot channels consume themselves on
    /// send) and an Arc<Mutex> to allow it to be safely shared between threads
    static ref SHUTDOWN_TX: Arc<Mutex<Option<Sender<()>>>> = <_>::default();
}

async fn hello(_: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, Infallible> {
    // Attempt to send a shutdown signal, if one hasn't already been sent
    if let Some(tx) = SHUTDOWN_TX.lock().await.take() {
        let _ = tx.send(());
    }

    Ok(Response::new(Body::from("Hello World!")))
}

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    let (tx, rx) = tokio::sync::oneshot::channel::<()>();
    SHUTDOWN_TX.lock().await.replace(tx);

    let make_svc = make_service_fn(|_conn| async { Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(hello)) });

    let addr = ([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000).into();

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_svc);

    println!("Listening on http://{}", addr);

    let graceful = server.with_graceful_shutdown(async {
        rx.await.ok();
    });

    graceful.await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

In this version of the code, we store the sender half of the shutdown signal channel in a global variable protected by a mutex lock, and then attempt to consume the channel to send the signal on every request.